# Wilks Lambda Tests for Canonical Correlations producing NaN

Tags: r, pearson-correlation

New here, hoping to get some insight on my results for a Wilks Lambda test for a CCA analysis in Rstudio. I have 12 predictor variables(params) and 13 criterion variables(ASC). Getting NaNs for the first 4 Pearson R values and a warning message.

Code:

```
fit.cca <- function(X, Y){
  
  library(candisc)
  
  
  # Fit CCA
  cca_model = candisc::cancor(X, Y)
  
  # Return fitted model containing canonical correlations and wilks lambdas
  return(cca_model)
  
}

cca_model = fit.cca(params, ASC)
cca_model$cancor
Wilks(cca_model)
```

Output:

```
Test of H0: The canonical correlations in the 
current row and all that follow are zero

      CanR LR test stat    approx F numDF    denDF   Pr(> F)    
1  1.00000      0.00000 -7299828308   144 -23.9250       NaN    
2  1.00000      0.00000         NaN   121 -16.2770       NaN    
3  1.00000      0.00000   -39750398   100  -9.6216       NaN    
4  1.00000      0.00000         NaN    81  -3.9561       NaN    
5  1.00000      0.00000        2660    64   0.7233   0.04474 *  
6  1.00000      0.00000         124    49   4.4226 5.768e-05 ***
7  0.89551      0.05849           0    36   7.1522   0.99980    
8  0.74240      0.29530           0    25   8.9316   0.99996    
9  0.53585      0.65791           0    16   9.8028   0.99998    
10 0.22582      0.92290           0     9   9.8856   0.99998    
11 0.14621      0.97249           0     4  10.0000   0.99723    
12 0.07914      0.99374           0     1   6.0000   0.85224    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Warning message:
In pf(Fstat, df1, df2, lower.tail = FALSE) : NaNs produced
```

I would like to know what is causing the NaN's and possibly how to fix it.

Comment: Without seeing the data, it is impossible to know for cetain. It is likely that your variables include pairs that are perfectly correlated with one another.

Comment: @dcarlson Yes it's seems so. Looks like a case of not enough data. Many thanks!